# Listing tags with custom html output

Tags: tags

I am trying to list all my tags in index.php, but it doesn't seem to be working and I am unable to see why. Looking at documentation, the properties are correct and and `get_tags()` is retieving an array.

```
<?php 
$tags = get_tags();
foreach($tags as $tag) { 
echo '<li><a class="button" data-filter=".tag-'.$tag->name.'" href="' . get_tag_link(
$tag->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tag->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tag->name.'</a></li>
';
} 
?>
```

I was able to achieve what I wanted with categories using:

```
<?php 
$categories = get_categories();
foreach($categories as $category) { 
echo '<li><a class="button" data-filter=".category-'.$category->name.'" href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a></li>
';
} 
 ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working

Comment: The code should output all my tags with the html I have added, but unfortunately nothing is being echoed. The codex offers a solution to list tags on the get_tags page, and using that outputs nothing, so I'm wondering is there something stopping this from working?

Comment: Your code works, you most probably have some other error. Turn debug on and check for errors.

Comment: I created some new tags and they appeared straight away, but not the old tags which seems strange. The old tags are just imported dummy content from wordpress, what would stop them being pulled in?

Comment: It is difficult to say. These old tags, do they have posts attached to them. If they are not assigned to posts, then they will not show up in your code

Answer (score -2):

I tested your code and it's working.
So you maybe have somewhere else an error.

Try `var_dump($tags);` and see if there's content.

Did you created some tags and assigned them to posts?